# ANTLR - putting full matched text into the AST

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I'm trying to have my AST nodes contain full text for the matched rule.  Trying

```
statement: 'blah' subrule ';' -> ^(MY_STATEMENT subrule $text);
```

doesn't work.
I'm looking at the instances of CommonTree I get back and they do contain startIndex and stopIndex fields but they appear to be indexes into the token stream and I don't see a clear way of reassembling the matched text from that.  This seems like such an obvious thing, 
can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can put square brackets after an imaginary token to put custom text in an (imaginary) AST node:

```
tokens {
  TEXT;
}

rule
 : subrule1 subrule2 -> ^(TEXT["custom text here"] subrule1)
 ;
```

But you can't refer to all text that has been matched with `$text` *inside* a rewrite rule. Inside rewrite rules, everything that starts with a `$`, is considered to be a label/variable of a rule:

```
rule
 : text=subrule1 other=subrule2 -> ^($text $other)
 ;
```

`$text` can only be used inside parser (or lexer) rules to grab all text the rule matched:

```
rule
 : subrule1 subrule2 {System.out.println("I matched: " + $text);} -> ^(...)
 ;
```

To get the text inside your rewrite rule, do it like this:

```
grammar T;

options { 
 output=AST; 
}

tokens { 
 MY_STATEMENT;
 TEXT;
}

statement
 : 'blah' subrule ';' -> ^(MY_STATEMENT subrule TEXT[$statement.text])
 ;

subrule
 : Digit Digit
 ;

Digit
 : '0'..'9'
 ;
```

which will parse the input `"blah78;"` into the following AST:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.  I should mention that as I was learning ANTLR over the last couple of week, I've been following your answers on SO and really appreciate the work you are doing for the ANTLR community here.